# Problem with metamask wallet with debian LINUX

Tags: metamask, wallets, linux, safe, debian

have a prblem with METAMASK wallet.I forgot my seedphrase but have the password,I use Linux Debian and I need to access to the safe,u have solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you have lost the seed phrase and you don't have a backup unfortunately you have lost access to your wallet.